# SPSS: check if an element of some variable exist in / is also element of another variable

Tags: spss

I want compute a variable which checks if an element of variable `v1` is also contained in another variable `v2`.

Let's assume the following example:
I have the following three variables: group-ID *(gID)*, person-ID *(pID)* (within the group) and lender-ID *(LID*), the ID of the person which lent money.

I then want to create a new variable *(loa)* which indicates for every person if this person has lent money to any other person. Or in other words, if the element of *pID* also appears in *LID*.

As an example see the following table:

```
+-----+-----+-----+         +-----+-----+-----++-----+ 
+ gID | pID | LID |         + gID | pID | LID || loa |
+-----+-----+-----+         +-----+-----+-----++-----+
+  1  |  1  |  2  |         +  1  |  1  |  2  ++  0  |
+  1  |  2  |  -  |         +  1  |  2  |  -  ||  1  |
+  1  |  3  |  4  |         +  1  |  3  |  4  ||  0  |
+  1  |  4  |  -  |         +  1  |  4  |  -  ||  1  |
+-----+-----+-----+   =>    +-----+-----+-----++-----+
+  2  |  1  |  -  |         +  2  |  1  |  -  ||  1  |  
+  2  |  2  |  4  |         +  2  |  2  |  4  ||  0  |
+  2  |  3  |  4  |         +  2  |  3  |  4  ||  0  |
+  2  |  4  |  1  |         +  2  |  4  |  1  ||  1  |
```

How can this be done in SPSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea here is to create a dataset which is a set of occuring elements in LID (for each groupId), which means that in this data set every combination of groupiDs and LIDs (The Id of Persons who lent money) exist only one time.

One way to do so is to use the `AGGREGATE` command:

```
* Name the original dataset, so it can be addressed later.
DATASET NAME main.

* Create a data set with unique combinations of groupID and LoanID.
* Bonus: Count how many loans a person has given.
DATASET DECLARE set.

AGGREGATE OUTFILE=set
/BREAK gID LID
/count_loans = N.
```

This data set can now be used as a lookup to identify the persons (pID) who loaned money. The `MATCH FILES` command does the job:

```
* Indicate wether pID has lent money (exist as LID in the set data) or not.
* Bonus: Add variable which counts the loans of that person.
* Note: "main" has to be sorted by "gID pID" 
*    and "set" has to be sorted by "gID LID".
DATASET ACTIVATE main.
MATCH FILES 
    /FILE *
    /TABLE set
        /RENAME (lId=pID)
        /IN loa
    /BY gID pID.
EXECUTE.
```